# Dropdown list select

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, onclick

Can I please have some help to call a Javascript function (getSelectedFilterText) when an Item is selected in a DropDownList.

Here is my code:

```
<select id="FeedBackFilter" name="FeedBackFilter" width="2000" onclick="getSelectedFilterText">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
</select>

function getSelectedFilterText()
{
    alert("test");
    var e = document.getElementById("FeedBackFilter");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(strUser);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something like not defining the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need parentheses like so:

```
onclick="getSelectedFilterText()"
```

But if you're only wanting it to happen when they change the selection, you should consider instead using the event 'onchange' like so:

```
onchange="getSelectedFilterText()"
```

This way it'll happen when they change the option, not when they click it ... which is different, they could click it without changing the option